# How to make this JavaScript function fade in or out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function that creates a DOM node and inserts a question:

```
function setHeader(){
    var questionBox = document.createElement("div");
    questionBox.setAttribute("id","question" + (questionNumber + 1));
    document.body.insertBefore(questionBox,scriptBox);
    var questionElement = document.createElement("h3");
    questionElement.setAttribute("id","question" + (questionNumber + 1));
    var questionText = document.createTextNode(questions[questionNumber].question);
    questionElement.appendChild(questionText);
    questionBox.appendChild(questionElement);
}
```

What I would like to know is how can I make the question fade in or out using jQuery?

The above function creates:

```
<div id="question1">
   <h3 id="question1">Question here</h3>
</div>
```

I just realised I have the same ID for the `div` and `h3`

Comment: Post the HTML as well.

Comment: you want the `questionBox` element to fade in instead of just appearing

Comment: There is no HTML in the `body` tags. The script creates the DOM node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (it uses jQuery since you have tagged it using jQuery)

```
function setHeader() {
    var questionBox = document.createElement("div");
    questionBox.setAttribute("id", "question" + (questionNumber + 1));
    var questionElement = document.createElement("h3");
    questionElement.setAttribute("id", "question" + (questionNumber + 1));
    var questionText = document.createTextNode(questions[questionNumber].question);
    questionElement.appendChild(questionText);
    questionBox.appendChild(questionElement);

    //adding to the current dom with fade In animation
    //for the fadeIn to work first the element must be hidden so we hide the target element first then adds it to the dom after that the fadeIn() animation method is called
    $(questionBox).hide().appendTo(scriptBox).fadeIn()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4M3Qv/)

- [jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)
- [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)
- [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: Is it possible to use jQuery within a file with vanilla javascript?

Comment: if you add jquery library in your page

Comment: like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>` before your script file

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. As a follow up would you know how to fade the question out when a `next` button is clicked? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Kane I hope you have noticed there is a duplicate id values... you need to fix it first then try something like `$('question' + (questionNumber + 1)).fadeOut()` - you need to get hold of the question `div` then call `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery provides fade in and fade out functions.

```
$('h3#question'+(questionNumber+1)).fadeIn();
$('h3#question'+(questionNumber+1)).fadeOut();
```

as a sidenote, ID attributes should be unique within a document.  The above code should work regardless, but having duplicate ID's may give you headaches down the road.